# Not getting custom attribute value of customer

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I have created a custom attribute as follows:

```
<?php

namespace RB\Certification\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), 'VERSION') < 0) {
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "verified_buyer");

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'verfied_buyer', [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Verified Buyer',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 90,
                'position' => 90,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'verfied_buyer')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
                ]);

            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to fetch in frontend block as follows :

```
 <?php

    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    namespace RB\Review\Block\Product;

    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     *
     * @author     Rocket Bazaar Team
     */
    class ListView extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView {

        protected $customerRepository;
        /**
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
            \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
            \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
            \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat, 
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
            \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, 
            array $data = [],
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
        ) {
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
              parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $urlEncoder,
                $jsonEncoder,
                $string,
                $productHelper,
                $productTypeConfig,
                $localeFormat,
                $customerSession,
                $productRepository,
                $priceCurrency,
                $collectionFactory,
                $data
            );
        }

        public function getCustomerDetails($customerId='') {
            if($customerId){
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                $cattrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('verified_buyer');
                return $cattrValue;
            }
            return 0;

        }

    }
```

Let me know where I am wrong. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo.

You've setup the attribute name as verfied_buyer in the database, and are then calling verified_buyer later on. Both should be the same, verified_buyer.

The line in UpgradeData class:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'verfied_buyer', [
```

Should be:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'verified_buyer', [
```